# Data-scraping from Pixel Monitor

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, prometheus, influxdb

I have an Optiheat 1-18es heat pump device (German: [overview](https://www.cta.ch/de-ch/waerme/2008/?oid=1999&lang=de&root=&pfad=https://produkte.cta.ch/index.cfm/Cta:NodecontentdataFrontend/showDetail/nodeId/212/nodecontentdataId/525/langLocale/de_CH)) on my local network that I can monitor via its IP address. I have never used data scraping before so I am unfamiliar with the html structure and scraping process. I was wondering if it is possible to scrape the changing values from this device and feed them into my influxdb database? I have read that that the scraped data should first be put into the prometheus data format.

Here is a screenshot of the IP address interface:
[image]

I can click on the arrows and go to different windows to see other data points.

From the network tab, I receive this information:

[image]

Comment: Probably there are api calls being made or a websocket connection, checkout the network tabs

Answer (score 1):

Please include more details of the device in your question so that others, familiar with it, can provide a more accurate answer.

In order to scrape metrics from the device you need to have an HTTP endpoint (you have this) that can be scraped for metric data in Prometheus' [Exposition Format](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#text-based-format) (this remains unanswered).

It's unclear from your screenshot but I assume that you either have a browser-based app that you point to your device and it queries it, returns the metrics (temperatures etc.) to the browser-based app and the app then renders the result in the HTML that you show (probable) **or** the device itself is generating the HTML output that you show.

In the former case (the device talks to the app and sends it data), you have 2 possibilities, the device is:

1. talking to the browser-based app using some proprietary protocol (likely).
2. already (!) using Prometheus metrics in the correct format to talk to the device (less likely).

In either case, using the browser's dev tools, are you able to monitor network traffic between your browser and the device? Can you include in your question examples of the URLs, requests and response that are being transmitted?

If the device is using a proprietary protocol, it's possible that you could write your own exporter for the device. This would convert the device's proprietary protocol into the Prometheus Exposition format. You would then scrape your exporter to read the metrics. It's quite likely that someone has already reverse-engineered this device and such an exporter exists.

If the device is using Prometheus' Exposition format already, I would expect this to be documented on the device's website as it would be a useful customer feature and I would expect the manufacturer to want to tell its customers about this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have edited my question with the information you requested. The machine is from a small manufacturer. I doubt they use the prometheus protocoll. Do you know a tutorial or something similar that shows me how to achive this?

Comment: You're welcome! It looks to be that it's using an old-school CGI script and is returning HTML directly to your browser. Can you provide more details on what device it is?

Comment: Sure. It is a heat pump. Here is a link to the product (only in german unfortunately): https://www.cta.ch/de-ch/waerme/2008/?oid=1999&lang=de&root=&pfad=https://produkte.cta.ch/index.cfm/Cta:NodecontentdataFrontend/showDetail/nodeId/212/nodecontentdataId/525/langLocale/de_CH

Comment: I've added that to your question. Perhaps someone who's famliar with it can help!